# Completion of curve $xy=x^3+y^3$ at origin.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

When introducing the conception of "completion" in algebraic geometry, one common example is the completion of the local algebra $\mathcal{O}_{C,o}$ at origin $0$ of curve $C:xy=x^3+y^3$. We know that $\mathcal{O}_{C,o}$ is the localization of $k[C]=k[x,y]/(xy-x^3-y^3)$ with respect to the maximal ideal $(x,y)/(xy-x^3-y^3)$, but then how to deduce that the completion $\hat{\mathcal{O}}_{C,o}=k[[x,y]]/(xy)$ by definition? I want some details.

Comment: I'm also a novice in this subject, but I don't think it's obvious from the definition. In Hartshorne, he does a similar example with the curve $y^2 = x^2(x+1)$. Here, the local ring is isomorphic to the same ring you've written $k[[x,y]]/(xy)$. He constructs formal power series explicitly allowing you to realize the isomorphism, but needs to use the fact that if $g$ and $h$ are two power series with linearly independent linear terms, there is an automorphism of $k[[x,y]]$ taking $g \mapsto x$ and $h \mapsto y$. This is non-trivial, but plausible if you do one or two calculations yourself.

Comment: Here's a reference for that fact: https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/5d29/09fba27e964dc365a7015f4920727abbebff.pdf